# Sharepoint calculated column shows year with comma

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am new to SharePoint and I am trying to display year with the help of calculated column. However, the resulting year is displaying with comma i.e. 2,016 instead of 2016.

Is there any easy way of changing it. I have given the formula `=YEAR(Created)`.

Answer (score 15):

Try to use this formula to get Year without fractions

```
=TEXT([Created],"yyyy")
```

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have set the datatype of the Calculated Column output to Number instead of String (Single Line of Text)

Answer (score 1):

There's one more easy way: if it's not a date and you don't know how many digits you'll need, just concatenate your number with an empty string like this:

`= "" & [NumericColumn]`